# How to correct use SpEL in XML Spring

Tags: java, spring

I would like to create util bean with my resources to images using static method

```
 ClassLoader.getSystemResource
```

and also

```
 File.separator
```

her is my util resource map

```
 <util:map id="ImageFiles" key-type="java.lang.String"  value-type="java.lang.String" >
    <entry key="success" value="#{ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icons"+File.separator+"png"+File.separator+"24x24"+File.separator+"OK.png")}" />
    <entry key="error" value="OptionPane.errorIcon" />
    <entry key="info" value="OptionPane.informationIcon" />
  </util:map>
```

But i got parse syntax error in Xml. It is possible to do it something like this??

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with XML first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use static method from SpEL you should study more about the last [one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
<entry key="success" value="#{T(com.my.proj.pack.ClassLoader).getSystemResource("icons"+File.separator+"png"+File.separator+"24x24"+File.separator+"OK.png")}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, how it was said earlier; Sample below:

```
<util:map id="nameToPeriod">
    <entry key="${validation.cycle.units.representation.month}" value="#{T(org.joda.time.Months).ONE}" />
    <entry key="${validation.cycle.units.representation.day}" value="#{T(org.joda.time.Days).ONE}" />
    <entry key="${validation.cycle.units.representation.hour}" value="#{T(org.joda.time.Hours).ONE}" />
    <entry key="${validation.cycle.units.representation.week}" value="#{T(org.joda.time.Weeks).ONE}" />
</util:map>
```